# Not getting "Go" button on android keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

Im using android:imeOptions="actionGo" for a edit text box. Its working properly on Android default keyboard. I'm getting "GO" button . But if i try to change the input method to either swype or LG keyboard on my LG device , I'm not getting "Go" instead im getting enter symbol. Why this is happening . I want Go button regardless of wt keyboard im using. Please can any one help me in this ?

Comment: then there is no any mistake by you it is mistake by keyboard developer...

Comment: for those, having similar problem, try adding android:singleLine="true"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly not all manufacturer implements correctly their custom keyboard so you wont be able to have the "Go" button.

For instance, on HTC phones you won't get something else than a "enter button" even if you set a search action: android:imeOptions="actionSearch". On a Motorola Droid it works fine.

On some phones you have to set the imeOptions in java code to make it works. You can have a try on your LG.

Comment: Bad luck. It will still work on some of your users phone. Samsungs keyboard works fine usually.

Answer (score 18):

Please add following two lines to your edittext:

```
<EditText
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionGo"/>
```

This will enable `Go` button on your softkeyboard

And to listen `Go` button Add

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if(actionId== EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO){
                //perfrom your action
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```